# How to track the .git directory in git, in its own store

Tags: git

The .git directory (such as the refs directory and HEAD file) are fairly critical to git. Is it possible to track the .git directory using its own object store? This w/could exclude (ignore) the objects directory itself, and perhaps the index.

Thus the .git directory structure would be with the git objects and recoverable from the *content* of those objects alone [Is that true for all the objects including pack and info dirs?]. Hence a simple copy and rename of all the objects to some innocuous file names, e.g. image0001.raw, image0002.raw, or dump0001.raw, etc., would allow you to maintain (recover) your git repo in a challenging environment (e.g. pressure to only use the existing paid-for big iron CMS)

Edit:
looks like [what-after-git-unpack-objects-to-get-the-actual-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343260/what-after-git-unpack-objects-to-get-the-actual-file) gets close to my use case ;-)

Comment: I can't work out if you're asking for something like what reflogs already do or if you're really asking a question about backup and recovery of git repos. Can you expand on your "challenging environment" and what relevance "pressure to only use the existing paid-for big iron CMS" has to your git repository?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, it's half and half. This use case is more relevant to larger 'passive-aggressive' organisations (a common situation) where you are expected on the one hand to 'toe the line', while given freedom to try 'relevant' ideas. So the large company will have a catch all CMS which is used to store everything: Word, pdf, source, drawings, test results, etc, in the old central repo style with tedious admin. Git is a challenge such as structure. This about having a side channel should one's obvious .git directory being mangled.

Comment: CMS = VCS? CMS describes something like wordpress to me

Comment: CMS - I was referring to the catch all Configuration Management System  style data repository that big companies have...

Answer (score 3):

Git already takes care of those internal files itself.  How would putting them into yet another git repo help anything?

Comment: If you delete HEAD then you are a bit lost, just as removing the refs directory would be a big problem, hence the idea that one takes a snapshot of those parts of the .git dir.

Comment: Well, if you delete `.git/HEAD` in your "level 2 repo", you are lost again. So you'd need another repo to make sure you don't corrupt your level 2. And so on …

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to backup the `.git` folder of a local repository:
If you break your repository, you simply clone it from the remote repo again. If you have no remote repo, simply create a local clone and push to it from time to time.